# Is it possible to import a library with name-solving priority?

Tags: haskell, module

Mind the following file:

```
import Common
main = print (length [1,2,3])
```

Common is a library that reorganizes functions from Prelude in order to export my favored versions (i.e., fold-based functions instead of list-based functions). This is giving name conflicts:

```
test.hs:3:15:
    Ambiguous occurrence ‘length’
    It could refer to either ‘Prelude.length’,
                             imported from ‘Prelude’ at test.hs:1:1
                             (and originally defined in ‘GHC.List’)
                          or ‘Common.length’, imported from ‘Common’ at test.hs:1:1-11
```

Since the idea is avoiding bureaucracy when creating new files, just using `Import Prelude hiding ...` wouldn't help here. Is there any way to tell GHC to favor `Common.hs`'s definitions over Prelude's?

Comment: I don't recall any flag beside `-XNoImplicitPrelude`. It's either not using the `Prelude` at all (beside a qualified import) or `hiding` the ambiguous functions.

Comment: Isn't there then a way to make Common.hs itself export everything from Prelude (except the functions it redefines)? So I can use `-XNoImplicitPrelude` and just import Common (since it will export Prelude's Float, Show, etc etc). Otherwise every Haskell file will have the same huge "import Prelude hiding (.........................)" header copypasted, which looks bad. I just need a way to move that logic to "Common".

Comment: So you want to re-export specific functions from an imported module in `Common`? That's possible. Have a look at [base-compat](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-compat-0.8.2/docs/src/Prelude-Compat.html)'s `Prelude.Compat`, which either exports the whole `Prelude` (as `Base`) if `base>=4.8.x` or specific exports (which is basically the whole `Prelude` again).

Comment: Okay, thank you! If prelude was small I could just do it for each function manually (like `length = Prelude.length`) but Prelude is huge (and I don't know how I'd export classes anyway). So, basically, `export everything from Prelude except (length, sum, etc)` (Edit: Actually, I'm not sure if that approach would be so bad, so I posted another question regarding the Class problem of that approach in particular.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to give priority, but one can easily override individual names. For example, to override `length`:

```
module Common where

import Prelude hiding (length)
import qualified Data.List

length :: Num n => [a] -> n
length = Data.List.genericLength
```

You can check that things are going well in ghci:

```
% ghci -XNoImplicitPrelude test.hs
GHCi, version 7.10.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
[1 of 1] Compiling Common           ( test.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Common.
*Common> :t length
length :: Num n => [a] -> n
*Common> :t (+)
(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
```